# Java Hibernate one to many fetch using Criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, one-to-many, many-to-one, distinct-values

I have a entity like this

```
public class Student
{
    private School school; //many to one...
    //setter and getters omitted
}

public class School
{
    private Set<Student>students; //Students...
    private Set<Owner>owners; //Owners one to many....
}
```

I have my code is quite easy..

```
 final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
 .add(filters)
 .setFetchMode("school",FetchMode.JOIN);
 final List<Student>students = criteria.list();
```

But I would like to retrieve the Owners as well. Later I could do:

```
for(final Student student:students)student.getSchool().getOwners.size();
```

But this would generate another `distinct` SQL query.

But I want to do it in a single Query is this possible?

I have tried:

```
final Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(Student.class)
.add(filters);
final Criteria ownerCriteria = criteria
            .createCriteria("school","school")               
            .createAlias("owners","owners");
final List<Student>students = criteria.list();
```

But this do not works because when I navigate through it:

```
for(final Student student:students)student.getSchool().getOwners.size();

Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: failed to lazily initialize a collection of role
```

Exception is thrown! Even I can see the `inner join` in `Hibernate SQL console..` but seems the `Owner` collection is not populate.

Is there a workaround for this?

Comment: You can use a fetch join but in this case, you are trying to fetch a lazily initialized collection (`java.util.Set`) which in turn requires a costly collection fetch in which you are also likely to get a warning from Hibernate. In this case, it would be better to execute a separate query instead to fetch the collection. (you can specify `fetch = FetchType.EAGER` for the owner's relationship but this is (highly) discouraged. I personally very much dislike it. This is merely considered to be a workaround rather than an actual solution).

Comment: Using fetch = FetchType.EAGER in School->getOwner it works but why  i couldn't make it work using the criteria approach??

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
criteria.setResultTransformer(Criteria.DISTINCT_ROOT_ENTITY);
```

Comment: Please update the entity class mapping details, You may need to use FetchType.EAGER which load all relationhips otherwise load  all the required object with FetchType.LAZY before hibernate session closed.

Comment: I use all relationships as LAZY.. and i dont wanna generate severals SQL queries i would love if i could do in only 1 query....